# Apache Ant and Nuggeta

Tags: ant, build, compiler-errors

I have been trying to use Nuggeta Server on my pc. But the problem is that when I run build.xml it is throwing sym,bol not found and other sorts of error can somebody help me??!!

Here is the compilation error shown by ant:

```
[echo] Compiling the java source files...
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\classes
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:5: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
[javac] import org.slf4j.Logger;
[javac]                 ^
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:6: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
[javac] import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
[javac]                 ^
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:8: error: package com.nuggeta.game.core.ngdl.nobjects does not exist
[javac] import com.nuggeta.game.core.ngdl.nobjects.NGame;
[javac]                                           ^
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:9: error: package com.nuggeta.game.core.ngdl.nobjects does not exist
[javac] import com.nuggeta.game.core.ngdl.nobjects.NGameMessage;
```

and more

```
 C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     public IncommingRequestStatus onMessage(NPlayer player, Message message) {
[javac]                                                             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Message
[javac]   location: class GameMessageServerInterceptor
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     public IncommingRequestStatus onMessage(NPlayer player, Message message) {
[javac]            ^
[javac]   symbol:   class IncommingRequestStatus
[javac]   location: class GameMessageServerInterceptor
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     public IncommingRequestStatus onAdminMessage(Message message) {
[javac]                                                  ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Message
[javac]   location: class GameMessageServerInterceptor
[javac] C:\Users\Development\Desktop\nuggetaWorkspace\NuggetaServer\src\com\nuggeta\gameserver\GameMessageServerInterceptor.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     public IncommingRequestStatus onAdminMessage(Message message) {
[javac]            ^
[javac]   symbol:   class IncommingRequestStatus
[javac]   location: class GameMessageServerInterceptor
```

And here is the build file

```
<project name="NuggetaGameServer" basedir="." default="jar">
<target name="jar" description="jar">
    <delete file="lib/myServer.jar" />

    <mkdir dir="classes" />
    <echo message="Compiling the java source files..." />
    <javac destdir="classes" debug="on" failonerror="yes" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="src" />
    </javac>

    <jar destfile="lib/myServer.jar">
        <zipfileset dir="classes/" />
    </jar>
</target>
```

I have imported the libs game server and myServer

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dependencies on 3rd party jars. One obvious one is a dependency on the [SLF4J logging framework](http://www.slf4j.org/):

- [Search for org.slf4j.Logger](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.slf4j.Logger%22)

Managing your compile and runtime dependencies is a non trivial issue in all programming languages, not just java. I don't have access to your code but your build file looks inadequate.

Assuming your 3rd party jars were located in a "lib" directory I would have expected something like:

```
<project name="NuggetaGameServer" basedir="." default="jar">

  <path id="compile.path">
    <fileset dir="lib"/>
  </path>

  <target name="jar" description="jar">
    <delete file="lib/myServer.jar" />

    <mkdir dir="classes" />
    <echo message="Compiling the java source files..." />
    <javac destdir="classes" debug="on" failonerror="yes" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="compile.path">
        <src path="src" />
    </javac>

    <jar destfile="lib/myServer.jar">
        <zipfileset dir="classes/" />
    </jar>
  </target>
```

Note the "classpathref" attribute on the javac task. This adds the jars in the "lib" directory onto the compile time classpath.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will try out your solution and get back to you.